# how to define SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to have my app script generate output to a SPECIFIC sheet, not the first sheet in the document.

i am looking to do the following:

1. Have 2 app scripts run on timers for a single google sheet document
2. App Script 1 will put data into sheet1, named "order_1"
3. App script 2 will put data into sheet2, named "orders_2"

my code currently puts the output into the active sheet, which is always the first sheet in the document

```
function import_Completed_orders_FromGmail() {
var threads = GmailApp.search('subject: "orders"');
var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

// Is the attachment a CSV file
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();  
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, 
csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
}
```

is there a way to define "ActiveSheet" by name? or to specify a specific sheet to put this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) method from [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).

In order to get a Spreadsheet object you will have to use one of the SpreadsheetApp methods to open a spreadsheet like [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid), `open(file)`, `openByUrl(url)`, `getActiveSpreadheet()`.

Comment: amazing! just tried it and worked perfectly. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get both sheet separately and use them in the code.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("order_1");
 var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("order_2");
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. i don't believe that will work. my code outputs the contents of an email attachment, attachment A, to sheet 'order_1', and what i want, is a secondary app-script to output the contents of a separate attachment, attachment B, to sheet 'order_2'. Currently I use 2 separate documents then use the "importrange" function to pull the data to one "master" document....but this method will become more and more complex as i add additional sheets.